# Function Groups vs Classes

Tags: abap

In ABAP I want to know which OO-Properties a function group has.

A function group has encapsulation, because I can put in global variables in a function group.
Polymorphism and Inheritance are not possible within a function group. Is this correct?

What about different instances of function groups? Is this an OO-Property at all and is it possible to accomplish this with function groups?

Comment: There is no such thing as "an instance of a funtion group". A function group is more like a class with static methods only. If there are no instances, then polymorphism and inheritance are of course off the table.

Comment: ABAPers never talk about function groups, only about their `function modules`. They are almost obsolete if there were not a few technical reasons to use the function modules. Official: [SAP Library - Function Groups](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/9f/db992335c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm) - [ABAP glossary - Function group](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfunction_group_glosry.htm). Somewhere, you'll find "Function modules in function groups are the predecessor technology of public methods in global classes." (let's add static)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [described in Clean ABAP](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/sub-sections/FunctionGroupsVsClasses.md):

- No instantiation. You cannot create multiple instances of the same function group.
- No inheritance. You cannot inherit from or let inherit function groups.
- No interfaces. You cannot provide two implementations for the same function group.
- No substitution. You cannot exchange a call to one function with a call to another one with different name but identical signature.
- No overloading. You cannot provide two functions with identical names but different parameters. (This is not possible in ABAP OO too, by the way.)
- Variable encapsulation. Function groups can hide internal state in private variables.
- Method encapsulation. Function groups can hide internal methods ("form routines").

Like Jagger and Sandra Rossi suggest, think of a function group as a `global abstract final class` with `static public/private` members.